# Translating Research Hypothesis to Equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, hypothesis-testing

Good day. I'm investigating the relationship of fall incidence in the last 12 months among the elderly who walk independently and those who require gait aids. Specificially, I aim to answer the following research questions with respective hypothesis:

1. What is the difference in association of fall history and predictor variables 
   (e.g. gait speed, cognitive impairment)  between independent walkers and aid 
   users? 
   Hypothesis: Gait aid users will demonstrate strong association between 
   fall history and speed/cognitive impairment whereas no association 
   was found in normal walkers.
2. What is the strength of association of fall history and cognitive impairment 
   among elderly gait aid users? 
   Hypothesis: Cognitive impairment among elderly gait aid users demonstrate 
   significant correlation to incidence of falls.

Proposed statistical analysis using log linear model.

I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to translate the above hypothesis into an equation.  I was thinking:

model y= aid use (1 or 0) | gait | cognitive impairment
Where y: fall in the last 12 mos.

Thank you in advance and regards.